# MATLAB:Selection-values instead of postions

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a cell array whose elements show the positions of values in a selection in the workspace. 
Now I want to keep the same cell array, but replace the positions by the the values.

My cell:

```
res{1}=[55 56 57 58]
res{2}=[80 81]
res{3}=[111 112 113 114 115 116 117]
```

My Selection "Channel":

55: 0.1
56: 0.2
57: 0.3
58: 0.4

What I want:

```
res{1}=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]
res{2}=....
```

I tried `res={channel}`
. But when I do this I only get one long vector.

Comment: what is `channel`? A vector or another cell array?

Comment: channel is name of my selection. I imported it as an Ascii-file

Comment: what is the output from `whos channel`?

Comment: Just for further reference, this blog post has a section *contents of a cell array* which might be useful. http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/

Comment: Class: double  size: 1400x1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res{1}` is the list of indices you want into `channel`, right? So just take those and put them back into the original cell array.  Since you  have multiples, might as well wrap it in a loop:

```
for n = 1:numel(res)
     res{n} = channel(res{n})
end
```

e.g. for `res{1} = [55 56 57 58]` this is equivalent to `res{1} = channel([55 56 57 58])`